# Inserting binary into MySQL from node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, cryptography

I'm using the crypto module to create salts and hashes for storage in my database. I'm using SHA-512, if that's relevant.

What I have is a 64 byte salt, presently in the form of a "SlowBuffer", created by `crypto.randomBytes(64, . . .)`. Example:

`<SlowBuffer 91 0d e9 23 c0 8e 8c 32 5c d6 0b 1e 2c f0 30 0c 17 95 5c c3 95 41 fd 1e e7 6f 6e f0 19 b6 34 1a d0 51 d3 b2 8d 32 2d b8 cd be c8 92 e3 e5 48 93 f6 a7 81 ...>`

I also have a 64-byte hash that is currently a string. Example:

`'de4c2ff99fb34242646a324885db79ca9ef82a5f4b36c657b83ecf6931c008de87b6daf99a1c46336f36687d0ab1fc9b91f5bc07e7c3913bec3844993fd2fbad'`

In my database, I have two fields, called passhash and passsalt, which are `binary(64)`s.

I'm using the `mysql` module (`require('mysql')`) to add the row. How can I include the binaries for insertion?

Comment: Why not store the binary data as a string in hex or Base64?

Comment: Data efficiency. Not that it matters or anything, but I feel as though it's better practice to avoid using less efficient data structures than necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I'm no longer using the mysql module, but the mysql2 module (because it supports prepared statements). This changes roughly nothing about the question, but I'd like to mention that those reading this who are using 'mysql' should probably use 'mysql2'.

Second, both of these modules can take Buffers as parameters for these fields. This works perfectly. To do what I was originally attempting to do, I have it like this:

```
var hash; //Pretend initialized as a 64-bit buffer
var salt; //" "

connection.query('insert into users set?', {..., passhash: hash, passsalt: salt,..., callback});
```

Additionally, I didn't realize that the crypto "digest" function had a default behavior with no parameter, which is to return as a Buffer.

This is not the best worded answer, but that's because no one seems to be paying much attention to this question, and it was my question. :) If you would like more clarification, feel free to comment.